# Paypal check out flow isOpen() function throws security error when polled

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I've implemented a polling checkout system in order to update my page asynchronously with an ajax call and not have to reload the page. Whenever a user starts the checkout flow I call a function that sets an interval that calls the dg.isOpen() function documented here [Under section titled : Setting Up Web Pages To Invoke the Digital Goods Payments Flow](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/digital-goods/IntegratingExpressCheckoutDG/)
 near the bottom of the page. Anyhow when that function is invoked, approximately every 500 milliseconds it throws a security error that is pretty straight forward.

```
Blocked a frame with origin "https://example.com" from accessing a frame with origin "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
```

Within the interval I have the condition

```
var isOpen = dg.isOpen()

if(!isOpen)
{
 //proceed
}
```

the thing is that while the window is open and the error is being thrown `isOpen` is `undefined` so the condition does not run but whenever I close the frame, it works! by returning false, and my code then runs, however depending on the amount of time a purchase takes it could throw hundreds if not thousands of errors. I am doing something wrong or did paypal intend for it to work this way?

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around which is to poll for the object.  I use jquery and this tells me whether or not the paypal light panel is open:

```
paypaldg = $('#PPDGFrame').length;
```

1 = open
0 = not open